# php redirect_to() function undefined

Tags: php

I am working on a database and I need to redirect the user to another page after the login process.

I am using the `redirect_to()` function. After the code executes it gives me the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect_to()

Here is what I tried

```
if($result){
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows == 1){

        $found_user=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        redirect_to("main.php");
        }

        else{
        redirect_to("index.php");
        }
}
```

Comment: It means that `redirect_to` doesn't exist.

Comment: redirect_to isn't a PHP method, if you haven't defined that function anywhere, then it won't exist... where did you get this function from?!

Comment: There is no built in function with that name. If you wrote one yourself, its out of scope

Comment: header() is the function you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `redirect_to` function before calling it. Try this code

```
    <?php
        if($result){
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($num_rows == 1){
                $found_user=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                redirect_to("main.php");
            }
            else{
                redirect_to("index.php");
            }
        }
        function redirect_to($location){
            header('Location:'.$location);
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use header :

```
<?php
/* Redirection vers une page différente du même dossier */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to()` isn't a function. You want to use `header("Location: main.php");`

As this is adding header information, it needs to be loaded before anything is passed to the page (I believe), so don't attempt to print anything out to the page before `header()` is called.

If you want to do something like that, I suggest using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to` doesn't exist, or if it does, it's not been included/required correctly.

Add this;

```
if( function_exists('redirect_to') == FALSE ) { //Future proofing...
   function redirect_to($where) {
      header('Location: '. $where);
      exit;
   }
}
```

If you already have output, I would advise you looking at using [output buffering.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily redirect using following header("Location: ....) syntax:

```
header("Location: main.php");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should equip your project with this function first as others have pointed. Alternatively refactor your code to use the builtin php function -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php