# PHP URL Variable Redirect

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a login page that submits to another page while adding a string to the end of the url. Would look something like this 'http://example.com?klc' I know I can use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` to get the string, but now I need to use it in a function to direct the user to a different page, based on the string. This is what I have written in the target file

```
<?php

$access = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

function user_admin_redirect($access){
    if ($access = "ppl"){
        redirect_to("ppl_admin.html");}
    else ($access = "klc"){
        redirect_to("klc_admin.html");}
    }
}

user_admin_redirect($access);
```

but for some reason the script dies. Any tips would be welcomed. Also, I have the system setup on my website, contact me if you are willing to help I can give you a test login.

Comment: You need to use `==` and not `=` in the `if-else` condition

Comment: You need to use proper looping method ` if ($access == "ppl"){
        redirect_to("ppl_admin.html");}
    elseif ($access == "klc"){
       redirect_to("ppl_admin.html");}
    }`

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi - How is that different from what I have commented? And munish -- looping?

Comment: Check your if-else statement

Comment: @MilanChheda nothing i commented without seeing your comment and now i will delete mine (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$access = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

function user_admin_redirect($access){
    if ($access == "ppl"){
        redirect_to("ppl_admin.html");}
    else if($access == "klc"){
        redirect_to("klc_admin.html");}
    }
}

user_admin_redirect($access);
```

1. You need to use `==` and not `=` when using `if`
2. You need to use `else if` and not just `else`
3. I am assuming `redirect_to` is some custom function that you have written which will redirect you to the mentioned page. If not, you should use `header('Location: ' . $location);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think redirect_to is a built-in PHP function.

You might need to use

```
header("Location:".$myPhpScript);
```

or you could define redirect_to, like:

```
function redirect_to($location){
    header("Location:".$location);
}
```

See more here:

[php redirect_to() function undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643694/php-redirect-to-function-undefined)

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Ya, I have it defined in another file